# Download specific files from url in r

Tags: r, url, download, wget

I would like to download multiple files (around 2000) from this url : https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/corp/scsb/wguo/data/Blended_VH_4km/geo_TIFF/

However, to limit time and space, I would like to download only the files that contain the name VCI.tif and only the years between 1981 - 2011.

I used wget on bash but could not find a way to select what I want. Additionally, the space consumed is huge (more than 140G).

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses `wget` and it works at least with the first 2 files, I have tested the downloads of a (very) small subset of the wanted files.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(httr)
  library(rvest)
  library(dplyr)
  library(stringr)
})

# big files need greater timeout values,
# since I'm using wget this is probably
# unnecessary
old_timeout <- options(timeout = 300)
getOption("timeout")

year_start <- 1981
year_end <- 2011
download_dir <- "~/Temp/"
wget_cmd_line <- c("-P", download_dir, "")

link <- "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/corp/scsb/wguo/data/Blended_VH_4km/geo_TIFF/"
page <- read_html(link)

files_urls <- page %>%
  html_elements("a") %>%
  html_attr("href")

wanted_urls <- files_urls %>%
  str_extract(pattern = "^.*\\.VCI\\.tif$") %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  data.frame(filename = .) %>% 
  mutate(year = str_extract(filename, "\\d{7}"),
         year = str_extract(year, "^\\d{4}"),
         year = as.integer(year)) %>%
  filter(year >= year_start & year <= year_end)

wanted_urls %>%
  #
  # to test the code I only download 2 files;
  # comment out this instruction to download all of them
  head(n = 2) %>%
  #
  pull(filename) %>%
  lapply(\(x) {
    wget_cmd <- wget_cmd_line
    wget_cmd[3] <- paste0(link, x)
    system2("wget", args = wget_cmd, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE)
  })

# put saved value back
options(old_timeout)
```

Comment: Genius !! thank you very much. It works. However, it stores each file in its own folder. Would it be possible to download them directly without saving them in their own folder?

Comment: @MyrTH Check the value of `download_dir` and `print(wget_cmd)` prior to calling `system2`. You can have a test run print out the wget command line without actually calling `system2` and downloading the files. In my tests, all files were downloaded to the same directory `download_dir` so I cannot tell what's going on.

Comment: They are dowloaded to the same directory but it creates sub-folders for each file as well. Any idea ?

Comment: @MyrTH Done: 1) `download_dir` must end with a bar `"/"`; 2) remove the line with `wget_cmd[2]` in the last pipe, `lapply` loop, the download loop (delete the line completely, it's not needed).

Answer (score 1):

Im sure this can be optimised but give this Base R solution a try (note this is not tested due to the size of files):

```
# Store the parent url of files we want to download:
# base_url => character scalar
base_url <- "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/corp/scsb/wguo/data/Blended_VH_4km/geo_TIFF/"

# Read in the html: html_string => character vector
html_string <- readLines(
  base_url
)

# Store the range of years to search for, 
# flattened into a regex pattern: 
# rng => character scalar
rng <- paste0(
  seq(
    1981, 
    2011,
    by = 1
  ),
  collapse = "|"
)

# Create a vector of urls requiring download: 
# input_urls => character vector
input_urls <- Filter(
  function(y){
    grepl(
      rng, 
      y
    )
  },
  unlist(
    lapply(
      strsplit(
        html_string, 
        "href\\="
      ),
      function(x){
        ir <- paste0(
          base_url, 
          unlist(
            strsplit(
              gsub(
              '^"', 
              '', 
              gsub(
                "(\\w+VCI\\.tif).*", 
                "\\1", 
                noquote(x)
              )
            ),
          "\\<\\/td\\>\\<td\\>\\<a"
            )
          )
        )[2]
      }
    )
  )
)

# Store the desired output folder here: 
# dir_path => character scalar
dir_path <- paste0(
  getwd(),
  "/geo_tifs"
)

# Function to create a directory if it doesnt already
# exist: r_mkdir => function() 
r_mkdir <- function(dir_path){
  if(dir.exists(dir_path)){
    invisible()
  }else{
    dir.create(dir_path)
  }
}

# Create the directory if it doesnt already exist: 
# directory => stdout(file system)
r_mkdir(dir_path)

# Generate a character vector of output file paths: 
# output_file_paths => character vector
output_file_paths <- vapply(
  strsplit(tmp, "geo_TIFF"),
  function(x){
    paste0(dir_path, x[2])
  },
  character(1)
)

# Download the files to the output paths: 
# .tif files => stdout(file path)
lapply(
  seq_along(output_file_paths),
  function(i){
    download.file(
      input_urls[i],
      output_file_paths[i],
      quiet = TRUE,
      cacheOK = FALSE
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for giving it a try but for simplicity and understanding sake, I will use Rui Barradas answer.

Comment: @MyrTH no worries, give it an upvote if you found it useful or did what you desired.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to download only the files that contain the name VCI.tif
> and only the years between 1981 - 2011.

This sound like task for [Recursive Retrieval](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html) feature of GNU `wget`, firstly consider more limited in size example: to download *VCI.tif files from https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/corp/scsb/wguo/data/Blended_VH_4km/geo_TIFF/ for year 2021 into current working directory, this can be done as follows

```
wget --no-clobber --no-directories --recursive --level=1 --accept "*P2021*VCI.tif" https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/corp/scsb/wguo/data/Blended_VH_4km/geo_TIFF/
```

meaning of used options: do not download file which was already downloaded, do not create subdirectories (save to current working directory), do recursive download, do not move more than 1 time (i.e. use only links given in page) and get only files with names like `*P2021*VCI.tif`.

I do not know way to describe 1981-2011 with single pattern so I suggest to use 3 following subsequently

```
*P19[89][0123456789]*VCI.tif
*P200[01234567890]*VCI.tif
*P201[01]*VCI.tif
```